# change content on hover CSS

Tags: css, css-counter

I want to change content of list on hover, i.e roman changed into numeric 1, 2, 3

I tried `li:hover` `li:hover:after` but both will add the content with existing content

```css
ul {
  min-height: 30px;
  width: 180px;
  margin-left:-30px;
  list-style-type: none;
  counter-reset: chrome-counter;
}

li:before {
  content: counter(chrome-counter, lower-roman);
  padding: 1px 2px;
  margin-right: 0.2em;
  font-weight: bold;
}

li {
  margin: 2px 0;
  padding: 1px 4px;
  font: normal bold 18px/32px  ms-sans, geneva, sans-serif;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 40px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #FFF;
  counter-increment: chrome-counter;
}

li:hover {
  padding: 4px 8px;
  color: #333;
  /*content : '..';*/
  counter-reset : counter(chrome-counter, upper-roman);
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 4px #222;
  border-radius: 1.5em .5em / 2.5em 2em;
}

.cc1 {
  background-color: #FF6766;
  color: #FFF;
}
```

```html
 <ul class="scheme">
      <li class="cc1" ></li>
     <li class="cc1" ></li>
     <li class="cc1" ></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're working on the :before pseudo-element, you need to apply all the states to that exact element... so not to the main element, nor the :after element, but the one that needs to change, which is `li:before` in your case:

```css
ul {
  min-height: 30px;
  width: 180px;
  margin-left:-30px;
  list-style-type: none;
  counter-reset: chrome-counter;
}

li:before {
  content: counter(chrome-counter, lower-roman);
  padding: 1px 2px;
  margin-right: 0.2em;
  font-weight: bold;
}

li {
  margin: 2px 0;
  padding: 1px 4px;
  font: normal bold 18px/32px  ms-sans, geneva, sans-serif;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 40px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #FFF;
  counter-increment: chrome-counter;
}

li:hover {
  padding: 4px 8px;
  color: #333;
  /*content : '..';*/
  counter-reset : counter(chrome-counter, upper-roman);
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 4px #222;
  border-radius: 1.5em .5em / 2.5em 2em;
}

li:hover:before {
  content: counter(chrome-counter, upper-roman);
  padding: 1px 2px;
  margin-right: 0.2em;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.cc1 {
  background-color: #FF6766;
  color: #FFF;
}
```

```html
 <ul class="scheme">
     <li class="cc1" ></li>
     <li class="cc1" ></li>
     <li class="cc1" ></li>
</ul>
```

Here is an example with changing into HTML content like you asked for in the comments:

```css
ul {
  min-height: 30px;
  width: 180px;
  margin-left:-30px;
  list-style-type: none;
  counter-reset: chrome-counter;
}

li:before {
  content: counter(chrome-counter, lower-roman);
  padding: 1px 2px;
  margin-right: 0.2em;
  font-weight: bold;
}

li {
  margin: 2px 0;
  padding: 1px 4px;
  font: normal bold 18px/32px  ms-sans, geneva, sans-serif;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 40px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #FFF;
  counter-increment: chrome-counter;
}

li:hover {
  padding: 4px 8px;
  color: #333;
  /*content : '..';*/
  counter-reset : counter(chrome-counter, upper-roman);
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 4px #222;
  border-radius: 1.5em .5em / 2.5em 2em;
}

li:hover:before {
  content: "";
  padding: 1px 2px;
  margin-right: 0.2em;
  font-weight: bold;
}

li span {display: none}
li:hover span {display: initial}

.cc1 {
  background-color: #FF6766;
  color: #FFF;
}
```

```html
 <ul class="scheme">
      <li class="cc1" ><span>#</span></li>
     <li class="cc1" ><span>0</span></li>
     <li class="cc1" ><span>*</span></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: You're welcome. Btw. you probably still have a few redundant lines there - I didn't clear anything, just added the code you needed so you can continue working on it.

Comment: I will be highly grateful if you give me some tips

Comment: No, no, I didn't have anything special to tell. It's just maybe you should check if you need that whole `li:hover` part now, since the main part is happening on the before element, so there might be a could rules you won't use... just that. It looks fine so far.

Comment: I have one more query, I want to change 10 into `*` 11 into `0` and 12 into `#` ( juts like phone dial pad). means custome content of the last row.

Comment: Ah, now that might be a problem, as I believe you would have to remove the counter and add the numbers and those two characters yourself, either as a CSS `content` value, or as a HTML content. Or you can just create two elements that will be exceptions and put content changes just for them

Comment: can we do like this, set content in html for last line and hide on normal state and show while hover. is that possible?

Comment: Yes, probably the simplest way would be to put it inside a span element and then have: `li span {display: none} li:hover span {display: initial}`. Actually, that's how I'd probably do the whole thing.

Comment: i think it's inline* . Thanks for the tip

Comment: [`initial`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/initial) sets whatever is the default value for an element, and yes, in case of span it is `inline`.

Comment: There, I wrote you a simple example with combining the counter and HTML content.

Comment: This works . Thanks for the help
`li:nth-last-child(-n+3) span {  display: none;}
li:nth-last-child(-n+3):hover span { display:  inline-block; }
li:nth-last-child(-n+3):hover:before { content: ' ';}`

Answer (score 3):

Use this selector:

```
li:hover:before {
    content: counter(chrome-counter, decimal);
}
```

```css
ul {
  min-height: 30px;
  width: 180px;
  margin-left:-30px;
  list-style-type: none;
  counter-reset: chrome-counter;
}

li:before {
  content: counter(chrome-counter, lower-roman);
  padding: 1px 2px;
  margin-right: 0.2em;
  font-weight: bold;
}

li {
  margin: 2px 0;
  padding: 1px 4px;
  font: normal bold 18px/32px  ms-sans, geneva, sans-serif;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 40px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #FFF;
  counter-increment: chrome-counter;
}

li:hover {
  padding: 4px 8px;
  color: #333;
  /*content : '..';*/
  counter-reset : counter(chrome-counter, upper-roman);
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 4px #222;
  border-radius: 1.5em .5em / 2.5em 2em;
  }

li:hover:before {
  content: counter(chrome-counter, decimal);
}

.cc1 {
  background-color: #FF6766;
  color: #FFF;
}
```

```html
<ul class="scheme">
      <li class="cc1" ></li>
     <li class="cc1" ></li>
     <li class="cc1" ></li>
</ul>
```